# Diffeomorphisms vs symplectomorphisms / volume conserving diffeomorphisms in an application

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, physics

This question needs a bit of background: one way to study the mechanics of deformation of a continuous solid body is by defining a reference body $B_0$, a connected, well-behaved subset of $R^2$ or $R^3$. In 3D one assumes that the boundary $\partial B_0$ is a closed, orientable surface; in 2D it is a closed curve.

A motion is then a map $\psi : B_0 \rightarrow B$, where $\psi = \psi(\bar{X},t)$, $t > 0$ and $\bar{X}$ is some label (usually a position vector) for points in the reference body $B_0$. In particular, motions are treated as diffeomorphisms parametrized by $t$.

A particular subset of motions involve those that conserve volumes / areas. For instance, in a planar motion, this would mean that infinitesimal areas $dv^a \times dv^b$ are conserved by the motion, i.e. the area form is not changed by the motion. A general incompressible motion would, similarly, preserve the volume form in 3D (if I am not mistaken).

In 2D, the (area preserving) motions are symplectomorphisms, not just diffeomorphisms. One expects that this imposes very strong restrictions on the map $\psi(\bar{X},t)$. In the odd-dimension (3D), one expects similarly strong constraints from the conservation of the volume.

The governing PDE for continuous bodies is the Cauchy equation of motion

$$
\nabla \cdot \sigma + \rho \bar{b} = \rho \left ( \frac{\partial \bar{v}}{\partial t} + \bar{v} \cdot \nabla \bar{v} \right)
$$

The velocity $v$ is defined as $\left. \dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial t} \right|_X$ and $\bar{b}$ is a specified vector field. There is, in general, a highly non-trivial, local relation (a functional) that relates the stress tensor $\sigma$ and the motion.

My questions are as follows:

(1) Is the presence of an incompressibility condition associated with any non-trivial, scalar, conserved quantities in the governing equation?

(2) It is known that there are some obvious restrictions on the velocity field, for instance $\nabla \cdot \bar{v} = 0$. However, does such a condition also impose non-obvious restrictions on other geometric quantities (e.g. the associated metric tensor)

Alternatively, is there a reason that symplectomorphisms vs diffeomorphisms / conserved volume form just does not yield too much more useful information beyond the obvious?

Comment: A terminological note: If you consider motions in $R^n, n>2$ then preserving volume is not the same as symplectomorphic. The latter means that $n=2k$ and the standard symplectic form $\sum_i dx_i \wedge dy_i$ is preserved.

Comment: You should edit your question, since you start with motions of $R^3$!

Comment: @studiosus Thank you. I have edited the body of the question. In 2D, it is a symplectomorphism, in 3D it is volume preserving, but it just occurred to me that in either case, it is a severe constraint on the type of motion. So my question is for both dimensions (2 and 3).